# How to have a bootstrap tooltip trigger before reaching the target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have been using bootstrap's tooltip plugin for a while and everything is working well. However, my targets are very narrow and so I would like to add a 1 or 2 pixel buffer around my target so that the tooltip triggers as you come close to the target.

How would I do this? Do I need to put an invisible target behind my actual target? Or is there a way to set use the "manual" trigger option and some javascript to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is the invisible target. You can make that invisible element a few pixels bigger and make the tooltip target that invisible element rather than your actual target.